# Obtener archivo con WGET

Tags: linux

Quisiera saber si existe la forma de descargar un archivo con wget el cual se obtiene presionando un botón de "Descargar" ej, de la siguiente pagina https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/planes-numeracion/descarga-publica.xhtml,

Agradezco su amable ayuda, saludos.

Comment: de poderse si pero solo con `wget` no. ya que valida con `tokens` que cambia por cada solicitud hecha a la web y una cookie= con `SID` , `1P_JAR` , `NID` ,`APISID` , `CONSENT` ,`primefaces.download` etc... que tambien cambian con cada solicitud!

Comment: Entonces ademas de utilizar wget sabes que más debería utilizar?                                    Gracias